# Why google map is not appearing in android app?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

My navigation application is crashing when I am trying to open google map activity. In my thinking the google map code may have some problems. The code of the map activity is given below. Can anybody help me with this ?

[image]

[image]

```
        Manifest.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.uit.awamimarkaz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.uit.awamimarkaz.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.uit.awamimarkaz.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA6v-b6CuuMcp7XMPQz6p5d_3hAxf*****" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.uit.awamimarkaz.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Sel_Dest"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.uit.CLEARSCREEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Sel_Process"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.uit.Sel_Process" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Map_Cnic"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.uit.Map_Cnic" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Map_Passport"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.uit.Map_Passport" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Map_Others"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.uit.Map_Others" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Online_Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.uit.Online_Map" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

        Online_Map.java
package com.uit.awamimarkaz;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
public class Online_Map extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.online_map);
        MapView mapView;
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}

    online_map.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: Post the text of the stack trace, not a screenshot.

Comment: @Shaheer Munir Shah, Please make sure that you selected Google api from project properties

Comment: I have added google play services lib but still not working

Comment: @Kamil is probably correct. When you started the project did you select an API that explicitly stated Google in it? If you just select an Android api for the build, maps will not work. You should be able to change this the target api in the properties section.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the API Key at a minimum.  Please follow the following link exactly and you should have no problem getting a basic map to work.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project.

1)Go to Properties.

2)Select Android from left bar

3)Select Project build target to Google APIs instead of Android APIs

**Updated**

Please put below line under application tag in manifest file

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

Hope you will find it useful.

Comment: have already done that. but please check my code for any error

Comment: @Shaheer Munir Shah could you please post stack trace from logcat.

Comment: @Shaheer Munir Shah Please check the updated answer. Hope this will works for you...